# Qt - record from .cvs file causing errors when pushed into vector

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I am writing a program that fills a QTableView with data from a cvs file.  I am also pushing that data into a vector of objects from a class.  I want to be able to catch any record from the file that may cause an out of bound error and move onto the next line without adding that record to the table or the vector.

Here is the function that populates the table:

```
QString filename = "currentstudents.csv";
QFile file(filename);
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

int lineindex = 0; 
QTextStream input(&file);

while (!input.atEnd()) {
    std::vector<QString> newRecord;
    QString fileLine = input.readLine();

    QStringList lineToken = fileLine.split(",", QString::SkipEmptyParts);

    for (int i = 0; i < lineToken.size(); i++) {

        QString value = lineToken.at(i);
        newRecord.push_back(value);       //this line is where out of bounds error comes from
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(value);
        currentStudentsModel->setItem(lineindex, i, item);
    }

    try
    {
        //creating a student object with the information parsed from the file

        CurrentStudent student(newRecord.at(0), newRecord.at(1), newRecord.at(2).toInt(), newRecord.at(3).toInt(), newRecord.at(4).toInt(), newRecord.at(5).toUInt());
        currentStudents.push_back(student);
     }
     catch (const std::out_of_range& e)
     {
            qDebug() << "OUT OF RANGE ERROR: " << e.what();
     }

    lineindex++;
}
```

If a record in the file is formatted in any weird way such as (,,,,,,) or without 6 commas to separate the data, it will load the record into the table improperly and then cause an out of bounds error eventually.  How do I get the program to just skip over the problematic line and move onto the next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a validation test:

```
while (!input.atEnd()) 
{
    // ...
    for (int i = 0; i < lineToken.size(); i++) {
        // load newRecord...
    }
    // validate..
    if (newRecord.size() != 6)
    {
         // print warning here ?
         // skip
         continue;
    }
    if (newRecord.at(0) == "")  // for example...
    {
         // print warning here ?
         // skip
         continue;
    }
    // more validation ?

    // add record
    CurrentStudent student(newRecord.at(0), newRecord.at(1), newRecord.at(2).toInt(), newRecord.at(3).toInt(), newRecord.at(4).toInt(), newRecord.at(5).toUInt());
    currentStudents.push_back(student);

} // end loop
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the method I ended up using after failing to get the try catch block to work.